# stop scrolling when DIV reaches footer

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, floating

I tried an scrolling-div-reachs-footer script. The script works fine if the richt div is longer dan the left div. But in my example the right div is shorter and the left div goes over my footer (footer is on bottom screen if text (class row) is short and other always on the bottom of the row div)

Can someone help me out for an solution? Changing the position to something else then fixed does not work.

my example code: http://jsfiddle.net/by4AP/

css:

```
    /* lay-out */

html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:11pt;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial,verdana;
    text-decoration : none;
    line-height: 19px;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:995px;
    display:table;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#header1 {
    display:table-row;
    width:995px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #CC00FF;
}

#footer {
    display:table-row;
    width:995px;
    height:100px;
    background-color: #FF6666;
}
.footertext {
    float: left !important;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.row {
    height:100%;
    display:table-row;
    background-color: #FF9999;
}
.cell-right {
    display:table-cell;
    float: right;
    width:500px;
    padding-right:10px;
    background-color: #3300CC;
}
.cell-left {
    float: left;
    width:245px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
.cell-left>div {
    top: 300px;
    position: fixed;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header1">header 1 </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell-left">
            <div>
            links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="cell-right">
            content rechts
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div class="footertext">
footer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
// linker menu

$(function() {
    $.fn.scrollBottom = function() {
        return $(document).height() - this.scrollTop() - this.height();
    };

    var $el = $('.cell-left>div');
    var $window = $(window);

    $window.bind("scroll resize", function() {
        var gap = $window.height() - $el.height() - 60;
        var visibleFoot = 100 - $window.scrollBottom();
        var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop()

        if(scrollTop < 300 - 60){
            $el.css({
                top: (300 - scrollTop) + "px",
                bottom: "auto",
            });
        }else if (visibleFoot > gap) {
            $el.css({
                top: "auto",
                bottom: visibleFoot + "px"
            });
        } else {
            $el.css({
                top: 60,
                bottom: "auto"
            });
        }
    });
});
```

What I try to do: When page is scrolling the left div stays on top til footer comes then he scrolls above whit footer.

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to make the "links" text sticky to the top when the user down scrolls down, this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/39james/pB49G/

I have cut down some of the content to make it easy to scroll.

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header1">header 1 </div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="cell-left">
        <div>
        links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links<br>links

        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="cell-right">
        content rechts
    </div>

</div>
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footertext">
```

footer

script:

```
$(function() {
    var sticky = jQuery('.cell-left').offset().top; 
    console.log(sticky);
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
        var windowTop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();   
        console.log(windowTop);
        if (sticky < windowTop) {
             jQuery('.cell-left').css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 });
        }
        else {
            jQuery('.cell-left').css('position','static');
        }
    });   
});
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:#000000;
    font-size:11pt;
    FONT-FAMILY: Arial,verdana;
    text-decoration : none;
    line-height: 19px;
}
#wrapper {
    height:100%;
    width:995px;
    display:table;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#header1 {
    display:table-row;
    width:995px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: #CC00FF;
}

#footer {
    display:table-row;
    width:995px;
    height:600px;
    background-color: #FF6666;
}
.footertext {
    float: left !important;
    margin: 7px 0px 0px 10px;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.row {
    height:100%;
    display:table-row;
    background-color: #FF9999;
    height: 280px;
}
.cell-right {
    display:table-cell;
    float: right;
    width:500px;
    padding-right:10px;
    background-color: #3300CC;
}
.cell-left {
    float: left;
    width:245px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```